# Julia not solving sparse Linear system

Tags: julia

### Introduction

I'm doing research in computational contact mechanics, in which I try to solve a PDE using a finite difference method. Long story short, I need to solve a linear system like `Ax = b`.

### The suspects

In the problem, the matrix `A` is sparse, and so I defined it accordingly. On the other hand, both `x` and `b` are dense arrays.

In fact, `x` is defined as `x = A\b`, the **potential** solution of the problem.

So, the least one might expect from this solution is to satisfy that `Ax` is close to `b` in some sense. Great is my surprise when I find that

```
julia> norm(A*x-b) # Frobenius or 2-norm
5018.901093242197
```

The vector `x` does not solve the system! I've tried a lot of tricks discover what is going on, but no clues as of now. My first candidate is that I've found a bug, however I need more evidence to make this assertion.

### The hints

Here are some tests that I've done to try to pinpoint the error

- If you convert `A` to dense, the solution changes completely, and in fact it returns the correct solution.
- I have repeated the proccess above in matlab, and it seems to work well with both sparse and dense matrices (that is, the sparse version does not agree with that of Julia's)
- Not all sparse matrices cause a problem. I have tried other initial conditions and the solver seems to work quite well. I am not able to predict what property of the matrix can be causing this discrepancy. However;
- `A` has a condition number of 120848.06, which is quite high, although matlab doesn't seem to complain. Also, the absolute error of the solution to the real solution is huge.

### How to reproduce this "bug"

1. Download the .csv files in the following [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1SZ5Uo97kVYHItRZ3FvQYpQ3-qwEseVO-?usp=sharing)
2. Run the following code in the folder of the files (install the packages if necessary

```
using DelimitedFiles, LinearAlgebra, SparseArrays;
A = readdlm("A.csv", ',');
b = readdlm("b.csv", ',');
x = readdlm("x.csv", ',');

A_sparse = sparse(A);

println(norm(A_sparse\b - x)); # You should get something close to zero, x is the solution of the sparse implementation

println(norm(A_sparse*x - b)); # You should get something not close to zero, something is not working!
```

### Final words

It might easily be the case that I'm missing something. Are there any other implementations apart from the usual `A\b` to test against?

Comment: Have you tried checking if `x` indeed a solution to the system? Perhaps by solving system as a non-sparse system, or by explicitly writing solution using inverse of `A` (or pseudo-inverse in case it isn't full-rank or square)

Comment: `x` is not the solution of the system. I've solved it with non-sparse and it gives different results. The matrix `A` is invertible. I could implement the non-sparse version, I just want to make sure there isn't an alternative which does not use dense matrices, as my program is quite computation-intensive and sparse matrices are really speeding the program up.

Comment: sorry for putting too much trust in library code and not enough in the question. The actual matrix `A` seems to produce a horribly conditioned sparse LU factorization (which is the method called for sparse matrices). `U`'s condition number is `2.879548971708896e64` which might be an overflow. One solution is to force Julia to use QR decomposition with `x = qr(A_sparse)\b`. This fixes the problem. But it should be worth opening an issue. (QR decomposition benchmarked about same speed as LU)

Comment: Thanks for your response. It has actually worked, that should do it for now. I will open an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve a sparse square system Julia chooses to do a sparse LU decomposition. For the specific matrix `A` in the question, this decomposition is numerically ill-conditioned. This is evidenced by the `cond(lu(A_sparse).U) == 2.879548971708896e64`. This causes the solve routine to make numerical errors in turn.

A quick solution is to use a QR decomposition instead, by running `x = qr(A_sparse)\b`.

The solve or LU routines might need to be fixed to handle this case, or at least maintainers need to know of this issue, so opening an issue on the github repo might be good.

(this is a rewrite of my comment on question)

Comment: Note the solve/lu routine is from SuiteSparse, so it's the standard one linked to in other languages and implementations as well. I don't think that in general defaulting to use QR is the right way to solve it in general either because at that point, why not default to SVD (which would then be more numerically robust, but even slower?). Maybe making a smart dispatch that is condition number based would be good, but IIRC testing condition number is expensive. Best might be to always lu and then qr if lu is sufficiently inaccurate?